# android how to add elevation to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a [`FoodCardFragment`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_food_card.xml) that contains a `CardView`.

And the `FoodCardFragment` is shown through the `FrameLayout food_card_view` of [`RandomFragment`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_random.xml).

The code of `RandomFragment` showing `FoodCardFragment` can be found [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/RandomFragment.java).

I have tried giving either the `Fragment` or the `FrameLayout` elevation, but on my cell phone, it is still not floating above the `RandomFragment`.

How should I add it?

[image]

Comment: apply margin 4dp on all side

Comment: @RajasekaranM on whose side?

Comment: set layout margin on all side if not work, use parent layout of card is any other layout

Answer (score 1):

Add margin if it's not working add parent layout as Linear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/food_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/food_card"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/food_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_image_place_holder" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Food Name"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/food_card" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tags_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/food_name" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/more_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tags_frame" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding margin works but the shadow created by the elevation is very unnatural.

Comment: you have add extra margin than your elevation so add margin as 10dp or reduce elevation as 4dp

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to put the `FrameLayout` inside a `CardView` instead of using a `Fragment` with `CardView` as its root, in my case the `Fragment` is `FoodCardFragment`.

This is the `FrameLayout`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/food_card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/food_card_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my `FoodCardFragment`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/food_card"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/food_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_image_place_holder" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Food Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/food_card" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tags_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/food_name" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/more_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tags_frame" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest declare

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to the activity on which your fragment is placed and use the attribute on the cardView

```
app:cardElevation="5dp"
```

Comment: That doesn't help.

Comment: i just went through your code on GitHub, your fragment is over MainActivity, have you included the hardwareAccelerated="true" under mainActivity in mainfest? if yes please test it by installing it on an emulator or a physical device, the XML preview doesn't show quite well

Comment: Either my cell phone or the emulator doesn't show the elevation. Code has been updated.

Comment: just change             app:cardElevation="5dp"
instead of android:elevation

Comment: You image doesn't give me the effect I am looking for. The food image is floating. This is expected. If you take a closer look, you will find out there is a large card beneath the toolbar around the food image. I want the elevation of that.

Comment: add the same attribute to the root of that view

Comment: I have tried and no attempts worked out, which is the reason why I ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin to `food_card_view` in `fragment_food_card`.

Add a wrapping frame layout.